# variance of log of ratio of chi-square variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, it.information-theory

Let X be a chi-square variable with two degrees of freedom.
Let A and B be to arbitrary constants, with $A>B>0$.

I need the variance of
$Y=\log(1+AX)-\log(1+BX).$

The mean is, maybe not simple, but doable, since it is the ergodic channel capacity of a Reyleigh fading channel, well known in communication theory, and is given by a sum of Exponential integrals, unless I recall incorrectly.

Comment: Indeed, $\int_0^\infty e^{-X}Y^2\,dX$ does not seem to have a closed-form expression.